# PHP file() function for extracting data from URL

Tags: php, weather-api

Although this may seem like a general question, how can you extract content from a URL such as (http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk) so that it can be formatted and used in the form of an array for each element in PHP? More specifically, how can I extract information from websites in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk');
$array = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

To get data from URL:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk');
```

Convert it in simple array:

```
$new_data = json_decode($content, true);
print_r($new_data);
```